# android - onactivity result viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabview

I have my `MainActivity` with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`.

`TabLayout` have 3 tabs: Tab1, Tab2, Tab3.

In my Tab2 I asked the user to activate the GPS (This really doesn't matter). The point is that I started some intent waiting for the result code or data:

```
status.startResolutionForResult((Activity) parentView.getContext(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
```

So, If I want to call `OnActivityResult` in my `Fragment` Tab2 then I should do something like this in my parent's (`MainActivity`) `onActivityResult`.

```
case ACTIVITY_RESULT_FROM_TAB2:{
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment               = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
                if(fragment != null){
                    ((Tab2Fragment) fragment).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
```

But it returns cast exception (Tab3 cannot be casted to Tab2) because the last fragment added was Tab3. How can I call `OnActivityResult` from Tab2 properly?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onActivityResult` funtion in `Fragment` of Tab2 not in activity, you will get call there.

To get the result in your fragment make sure you call `startActivityForResult(intent,111);` instead of `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,111);` inside your fragment.

You can do like this..

Overide `onActivityresult` in Activity class and call a function of `Fragment` from there and pass the result.

Comment: Yes, I already override onActivityResult in Tab2 but this still return me "Tab3 cannot be casted to Tab2"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ViewPager and you must have implemented PagerAdapter.

so you can Refrence Tab2 Fragment by index.

in this way:

Fragment fragment=pagerAdapter.getItem(1);

Try this

```
Tab2Fragment fragment= (Tab2Fragment)  pagerAdapter.getItem(1);
fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I mean, it calls OnActiviyResult in Tab2Fragment but I get null expection because my TextView is binded in OnCreate and with your method OnCreate seems like is not being called.

Comment: share story of TextView you did not discussed it.
i will provide solution for that nullpointer exception i need more detail

Comment: Tell me the complete scenario what you want to do?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XkNTlgU.png Thats my OnCreateView in Tab2. Well, It checks if GPS is enable or not, if is not enable show a popup like this http://i.imgur.com/aIMC8e9.png and I need to get the Result in onActivityResult in Tab2

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this :
Add fragment to list in view pager:

```
ArrayList<Fragment> fragment=new ArrayList<>();
    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment,String titles)
{

    this.fragment.add(fragment);
    this.tabTitles.add(titles);
}

public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
   return fragment.get(position);
}


call getFragmnet function from activity:

viewpagerAdapter.getFragmnet(viewpager.getcurrentIndex())
```

Comment: Didn't work either because  I get null execption cause my textview is not binded. I mean in onactivityresult in TAB2 I have to change the text of my textview, but I get that the textview is null.